# Django: prevent Form to crash when akward date format is used

Tags: django, date, validation, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    template_name = 'users/edit_profile.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].help_text = _(
            'Providing your email would enable you to recover your lost password')


    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'birthday',
            'language',
            'headshot',
        )
```

with  user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    birth_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Birth year'), default=0)
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name=_(
        "birthday"), null=True, blank=True)
    headshot = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Avatar'),
                                 null=True, blank=True, default='user_headshots/user.png', upload_to="user_headshots/")

    language = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Language'),
                                max_length=10,
                                choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
                               default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

and view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def edit_user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EditProfileForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            # delete the cached value from self.__dict__:
            request.user.refresh_cached_profile_attributes()

            form.save()

            messages.success(request, _(
                "Your profile was succesfully modified"), extra_tags='text-center')

            return redirect(request.GET.get('next'), 
                            extra_query= {'first_play': True} if 'first_play' in request.GET else {}
                            )
    else:
        context = {}
        
        
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        context.update({'form': form})

        return render(request, 'users/edit_profile.html', context)
```

I had a user use a strange format for birthday `"25,2,96"`, which led the django  application to crash:

```
The view users.views.edit_user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

not much more information in the Traceback !?!

Looking into the django code and internet, I was amazed that the `DateField` `formfields` did not come with embedded validators

There are plenty of information on internet about setting specific dateformats for a specific `DateField`, but I wasn't able to find one kind of best practice that would work with all sort of localized date formats.

Everything I found is very complicated for such a trivial issue, and I'm pretty sure there is a neat and easy to implement solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: show the relevant views